# Property of a non object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to find out why I'm getting a Trying to get property of non-object. I'm not completely skilled with objects and arrays but i'm trying. Here's the code and the error message. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/sitemodel.php

Line Number: 208 and 215



function getSubMenuPages()
{
    $this->db->select('site_menu_structures.id');
    $this->db->from('site_menu_structures');
    $this->db->where('site_menu_structures.short_name', 'mainnav'); 
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $menu_id = $query->row()->id; 

    $this->db->select('site_menu_structures_links.id, site_menu_structures_links.short_name, is_category');
    $this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links');
    $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links.menu_structure_id', $menu_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $linksArray = $query->result();
        foreach ($linksArray as $key => $link)
        {
            if ($link->is_category == 'Yes')
            {
                $linksArray->{$key}->child_links;
                $this->db->select('site_menu_structures_links_children.link_name');
                $this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links_children');
                $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_children.site_menu_structures_links_id', $link->id); 
                $query = $this->db->get();
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
                {
                    $linksArray->{$key}->child_links = $query->result();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $linksArray;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Is $this->db->get(); always returning an object? In the case of ADOdb, it returns false if the query failed - thus, you'd want your if statement to be something like `if ( $query && Query->num_rows() ) {`

Comment: Can you flag lines 208 and 215, as there is no line-number gutter.

Comment: It has to be the lines containing $linksArray->{$key}->child_links, as the second occurrence is on the 7th line after the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be `$linksArray` is an array, not an object so the line

> $linksArray->{$key}->child_links;

will not work. In any case, this line does nothing so why have it at all?

Where you assign a value to this "property", try this instead

```
$linksArray[$key]->child_links = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Trying to get property of non-object"

this type of errors only exist if you try to treat a variable as an object instance and you actually failed to create that instance successfully try to check this part of the code if this is really an object or not:

```
$linksArray->{$key}->child_links
```

this is on the bottom of your code.